# Ordinal logistic regression with stacked data

Tags: logistic, ordinal-data, fixed-effects-model

I have a panel dataset (covering 3 periods), in which we've stacked the data so that each individual respondent has 4-8 observations. The independent and dependent variables are both on a Likert scale.
My general idea is: `dependent = indep1 + gend + indep1*gend`, with fixed effects.

I found this [paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X20930984) that seems to do a similar thing (ordinal logistic regression with fixed effects, `feologit` in Stata). I'm basically just wondering whether this still works for stacked data?

My dataset looks like this:

```
Resp  depen Indep1  gend
 1       1      1   f
 1       2      2   m
 1       4      3   f
 2       2      4   f
 2       4      1   m
 3       3      2   f
```

A paper did a similar thing to what I intend to do and used alternative specific multinomial probit - but I have the Likert scale outcome, more time periods and I'd rather not estimate separate models for the gender (`gend`).

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a place for a proportional odds ordinal logistic model with random effects (random intercepts) for subjects.  See for example the R `mixor` package or the [R rmsb package](https://hbiostat.org/R/rmsb).